# Jquery Cycle Plugin - webkit browsers start a paused cycle on refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, google-chrome, safari, cycle

This is my code

```
$('#gallery-photos').cycle({ 
            fx:     'fade', 
            speed:   500, 
            timeout: 3000, 
            pager:  '#gallery-navigation',
            requeueOnImageNotLoaded: true,
            after:  onAfter
        }).cycle('pause');
```

As you can see the cycle will stop after init, as Malsup itself showed in some posts around the internet... but when i refresh page with Chrome or Safari, the cycle starts, ignoring the pause command.

I have another slideshow in the same page that autostarts as default, but it is not involved with the previous one

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header-gallery-conteiner').cycle({ 
         fx:'scrollUp', 
         speed:  888,
         timeout: 4000,
         requeueOnImageNotLoaded: true
     });  
 });
```

How can i make it able to pause correctly even after refresh with webkit browsers?

Comment: is your first block of code also in a `$(document).ready(function() { .. });` ?

Comment: [ SOLVED ] i solved creating a function that gives to the dynamic gallery the cycle function only when document is fully loaded.. so $(document).ready(...), this function sais that the gallery-photos div must be "cycled". Thank for your support as always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move you first block of code inside the $(document).ready() event like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header-gallery-conteiner').cycle({ 
         fx:'scrollUp', 
         speed:  888,
         timeout: 4000,
         requeueOnImageNotLoaded: true
     });
     $('#gallery-photos').cycle({ 
         fx:     'fade', 
         speed:   500, 
         timeout: 3000, 
         pager:  '#gallery-navigation',
         requeueOnImageNotLoaded: true,
         after:  onAfter
     }).cycle('pause');
 });
```

You should only have one function assigned to `$(document).ready()`, so if you have it also somewere else on your page get rid of it, and add the code to to the function above

Comment: Thank for your answer Jules, it is not in the $(document).ready(...) so i'll try right now

Comment: Thank you again Jules but it doesn't work because the second gallery (gallery-photos) is dinamically generated by an included php file... i tried to insert only $('#gallery-photos').cycle('pause');  in the $(document).ready() but without results... is this include situation the mother of all the problems?

Comment: [ SOLVED ] i solved creating a function that gives to the dynamic gallery the cycle function only when document is fully loaded.. so $(document).ready(...), this function sais that the gallery-photos div must be "cycled". Thank for your support as always – GiovanniDema 0 secs ago edit